# NotifySubscribers is not refreshing UI (Writable Computed)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a writable computed inside a custom binding to format an observable. However, when the users remove the formatted mask, the read function wont trigger, since the observable is removing all non digits, ok, its working as it should be, so i added the notifySubcribers to call read everytime, even if the observable value didnt change and its working, but the ui element isnt refreshing the new value (read return)

Follow the code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.conta = {
    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(), formatted = ko.computed({
        read : function() {
            var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (!val) return val;
            if (val.toString().length < 6) { 
                val =  zeroPad(val, 6);
                observable(val);
            }
            return val.toString().slice(0, val.toString().length - 1) + "-" + val.toString().slice(val.toString().length - 1);
        },
        write : function(value) {

            if (value) {
                value = zeroPad(value, 6);
            }

            observable(value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
            observable.notifySubscribers();
        }
    });

        if ($(element).is('input')) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                numbersOnly : true,
                maxLength : 10,
                value : formatted
            });
        } else {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
                numbersOnly : true,
                text : formatted
            });
        }

        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings : true
        };
    }
};
```

Can someone give me some directions here?

Thanks :D

Comment: Could you extend your code and make it into a small repro? There's a "Stack Snippet" button on the editor's toolbar that would even allow you to make it runnable on SO.

Comment: Hey, i did this fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lyad24p4/  if you erase the "-", knockout will invoke the read method.. but the return value isnt updating the element =(

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `formatted` computed obs with `notify: always`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.conta = {
    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(), formatted = ko.computed({
            ...
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
...
```

This will force it to notify always even if there is no changes.